# How to disable minimize, maximize button in the browser?

Tags: javascript

How to disable minimize, maximize button in the browser using JavaScript?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?

Comment: just displaying the qrcode image. its 50X50 only. also display this right corner of the page.. behind this popup the main window should be visiable.. thats y only... thanks..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot (consistently).  Deliberately malicious actions are generally restricted by browsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.open("mypage.html","mywindowname", "toolbar=no,menubar=no");
```

WIll give you a new window without the menubar and without the toolbar.  That's what I'm assuming you want when you say "disable".  If you just want to disable the functionality while still showing the buttons, then you can't.

Look [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for a reference on the window.open() method.

Comment: +1 for the closest way to achieve it, but it's kinda sketchy -- Chrome ignores this with respect to sizing controls, minimize, and maximize buttons.  IE8 disables the maximize, but allows minimize.

Comment: firefox browser didnt support anything like below,

<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");
}
</script>

Comment: @squillman I tried you code but in IE i still can use minimize button, how even the maximize one is working and its disable now. Could you please help me how to disable minimize key in same way, I am not sure if menubar include both the button

Comment: It's not working. If it's working in any browser mention that also.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another approach, you can send key strokes for Alt, Space,N.

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
function Minimize()
{
    WshShell.SendKeys("% n");
}
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY >
<TABLE width=100%>
<TR align=right>
    <TD><input type="button" name="Button" onclick="Minimize()" value="minimize" /></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
```

Comment: This most likely only works in IE on Windows. I am not aware of any other browser which supports ActiveX. Nor am I aware of any current IE for anything but Windows. (There is no current IE for Mac, no?)

Answer (score -2):

For Firefox:

```
<script>
    window.open("http://www.google.com/", "Google", "dialog=yes");
</script>
```