# How can I disable the browser's minimize button when launching my flex application?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flex3, flex4

How can I disable the browser's minimize button when launching my flex application?

Answer (score 3):

From a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser):

> You cannot (consistently).
>   Deliberately malicious actions are
>   generally restricted by browsers.