# Disable Browser's Minimize button using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable minimize, maximize button in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser)

I am using php and javascript.I am using IE, Please tell me how can i disable the minimize button using javascript. I have used this

```
 window.open('url','',"fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes,minimize=no",true);
```

But only

```
minimize=no
```

or

```
minimize=0
```

is not working. I do not want to use open a box.can we call a function on minimize the browser ?

Comment: Not possible, for good reason.

Comment: There are some constructive answers in this [thread] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser)

Comment: @janenz00 Just so you know, to link a url in a comment you can do `[thread](link)`.

Comment: @janenz00 without the space in front of the URL. :)

Comment: @Daedalus - I posted it as an answer, but it was converted to comment. Just edited.

Comment: Looks like I am missing something. Will figure it out later. Let us focus on window minimizing :-D

Comment: It's because you put a space between the brackets.  Remove it and it will work.

Comment: @janenz00 Check the the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) for all the syntax. You can always get to it by clicking `help` or the `?` next to the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent the browser window from being minimized. The OS handles this functionality and it would be a security issue if you could...

Imagine one of those popup ads that you could not close or minimize. The horror!

You *can* use software designed for this purpose. Google for "public browser" or "browser kiosk" and you'll find something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way modify the client browser in such a way.