# Javascript onclick function Opening image

Tags: javascript

can anyone answer my question how to stretch image to width 10% and height 100% without having a whitespace?
i have Jscript to open this image  code

```html
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.open('Gallery/a1.JPG','no','scrollbars=yes,width=421,height=422%')" >
       View Larger
    </a>
</p>
```

and gives me this output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMFPp.jpg

checked photoshop it doesn't have whitespace, when i view the image using jscript and maximize the window it gives me white space. why is the whitespace appearing? the fudge!

Here's the code

```html
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.open('Gallery/1.JPG','no','scrollbars=yes,width=429,height=290')" >
        <img src="Gallery/1.JPG" width="200" height="150" />
    </a>
</p>
```

it's how to use javascript to open an image without having to have a whitespace excess area at it's corners.

i tried photoshop and photoshop shows no excess whitespace, while when i use javascript to open the image link it gives me a white space, how do you eliminate the white space? or how do you stretch the image width and height? i tried adjusting width and height parameters but the wider i stretch it gives me more white space...

Help i'm stuck

Comment: You should post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: A fiddle will more easier to debug.

Comment: @user1671639 here's fiddle if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/Dp4Ja/

Answer (score 0):

> **What you called is not actually `whitespace` of the image, it is the
>   window size that you have mentioned below.**

```
onClick="window.open('Gallery/1.JPG','no','scrollbars=yes,width=429,height=290')" >
```

See the difference,

```
<img src="Gallery/1.JPG" width="200" height="150" />
```

> **Actual image size:** width="200" height="150"
>
> **New popup window size:**
>   width="429" height="290"

So you have same values in both.  If it is a single image, you can directly add it.

For **dynamic**, then you have to use `Javascript` or `jQuery`.  Here I will give you an idea using **`jQuery`**.

**HTML:**

```
<p> <a href="javascript:;">
  <img src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10442396486498843578" />
  </a> 
</p>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var src = img.prop('src'); //GET IMG SOURCE
    var wid = img.width(); //GET IMG WIDTH
    var hie = img.height(); //GET IMG HEIGHT
    window.open(src, 'no', 'width=' + wid + ',height=' + hie);
});
```

Try changing the images in this [**Fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp4Ja/1/) and [**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp4Ja/2/)

Hope I have given a clear picture.

Comment: is there a way to lock or stretch the image to fit the window page, so when you maximize the window it won't show white spaces produced by window size?

Comment: @user2610699 You mean, to lock the browser from maximizing and minimizing?  Thats not fair enough.  Check this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser