# How to remove minimize and maximize property of a window by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove minimize and maximize button from a window. So that the Popup window that appears in front should not be able to disappear from the front until it is closed. Also, the background window can not perform any operation until the front window popup is closed,even I cant minimize or maximize the background window.So, Can anybody tell me how to do the functionality for this in JavaScript?

Comment: Post your code that you tried, we are not here to code for you

Comment: It's not done the way you are suggesting. Please do some research starting with search engine input of "html modal dialog jquery".

Comment: It's not a popup, it's some content you make it appear with higher z-index with background mostly a little faded which looks like it locks everything else on that page until you response to the "modal"

Answer (score 0):

i think this link to be helpful to you
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser)
another one

[toolkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/popwin/index.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform actions on the browser resize able parts except in IE.
Check out this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for more refernce.