# How to disable minimize maximize button in the browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an about:blank page in a new browser window that is 200px wide and 100px tall.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("bigpage.html", "resizable=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,fullscreen=0,titlebar=0", "width=2000,height=1000");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable minimize, maximize button in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754823/how-to-disable-minimize-maximize-button-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Disabling minimise and maximise can be malicious.

Comment: the max is the only one that will be greyed out. in IE

Comment: Yes. No (decent) browser will let you screw with those. Don't rely on it working.